# Jenkinsfile with shell Linux - Verify if a specific port number accept connections

Tags: linux, jenkins-pipeline

on jenkinsfile, I set the following code in order to verify if port number 19081 accept the connectivity.
If i run this comman directly on linux server, it works fine with response code '0', 
but on jenkinsfile the check fails because for each iteration I receive the message: "Ncat: Connection refused." 
 despite the application on linux server is up and running and respond on port 19081.
Could you please help to understand why on jenkinsfile I receive "Connection Refused"?

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash -ex
for i in {1..10}
do
    echo "Check application listening $i times"
if  echo 'QUIT' | sleep 4 |nc -w 5 0.0.0.0 19081 ; then
    echo "Application is up."
    break
else
// Here I always receive "Ncat: Connection refused. (On linux server the application is up and responds)
  echo "Retry.. $i times"
  if [[ $i -eq 10 ]]; then
    exit 1
  fi
fi; 
done
'''
```